# Accounting for Vinylic Carbocation instability

Tags: organic-chemistry, carbocation

I read that due to geometrical constraint, positive carbons in an aryl carbocation exhibit sp^2 hybridization instead of sp^1. The empty p-orbital is forced into a hybridized position via geometrical constraints. This then explains the instability of the carbocation as the positive carbon is attached to a significantly more electronegative carbon. Understanding that carbons with more "s-character" display more electronegative behavior, please clarify the following questions:

1) What is the hybridization of the positive carbon in a vinylic carbocation?

2) Are geometrical constraints present in vinylic carbocations?

3) What makes a vinylic carbocation unstable?

Origin: [Why are vinylic and arylic carbocations highly unstable?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/10509/why-are-vinylic-and-arylic-carbocations-highly-unstable)

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/10509/why-are-vinylic-and-arylic-carbocations-highly-unstable

Comment: @Mithoron The link your provided is exactly where my question is derived from. I had already read everything on it before I made the post.

Comment: Then you should have linked it yourself. BTW I don't see a proper question in your post.

Comment: Better edit your question to be actual question, and don't waste time on annoying people who can tell you how to improve it.